# Workbook.Worksheets.Columns() with numbers instead of a string?

Tags: excel, vba

Currently I am able to do one of two things.

I can either use a string showing what columns I want to change the width of or I can use a column number one at a time like this:

This works fine as a string.

```
re_wb.Worksheets(1).Columns("K:J").ColumnWidth = 23
```

The problem is I am having to dynamically find the last column and then add two more columns to the sheet. This is accomplished with finding the last column then just adding a value to the 1st cell for a header using `+1` and `+2` on the last column number.

```
last_col = re_wb.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, re_wb.Worksheets(1).Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
re_wb.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, last_col + 1).Value = "Correct Per CL"
re_wb.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, last_col + 2).Value = "Is reassignment needed?"
```

For two columns its not such a big deal to write two lines with the last column number +1 and +2 respectively to edit their width but considering a range of columns can be worked with a string is it possible to use two sets of numbers? (Or more numbers depending on how many columns I may need to edit at once.)

```
re_wb.Worksheets(1).Columns(last_col + 1).ColumnWidth = 23
re_wb.Worksheets(1).Columns(last_col + 2).ColumnWidth = 23
```

I have tried something like this:

```
re_wb.Worksheets(1).Columns(last_col + 1, last_col + 2).ColumnWidth = 23
```

With no luck. Seeing that I cannot predict what letter the column will be is it possible to define a range of columns using numbers or will I need to simply need to do one at a time like I already have above?

Comment: Guess this was an easy one, you got the same answer 3 times within 2 minutes. :)

Comment: @vacip ya in retrospect I should have thought of that solution on my own. It seams so obvious now.

Comment: @Mike-SMT hindsight is always 20/20 ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no such thing as a "Column" in the Excel object model - `Worksheet.Columns(foo)` returns a `Range`. Just build the appropriate `Range` and use that to set the column widths:

```
With re_wb.Worksheets(1)
    .Range(.Cells(1, last_col + 1), .Cells(1, last_col + 2)).ColumnWidth = 23
End With
```

Comment: For some reason I always use the .EntireColumn in such cases. Not sure why though, I'll research this...

Comment: @vacip I am not sure if entire column or just column would make a difference here. Both result in the same spacing for the entire column. Should be fine either way. Maybe the entire column option might cost more cpu time.

Answer (score 2):

```
Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 3)).EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = 15
```

Obviously you'll want to qualify what sheet you're refering to rather than just Range or Cells

Answer (score 1):

If you know the first and last column that you want to change the width on you could convert the numbers to letters (see this site: [Number to Letter](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/the-code-vault/vba-code-to-convert-column-number-to-letter-or-letter-to-number)) and then convert the whole range.

Here is an example of this method:

```
Dim start_column As String, end_column As String
Dim last_col As Integer
last_col = re_wb.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, re_wb.Worksheets(1).Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

start_column = Split(Cells(1, last_col + 1).Address, "$")(1)
end_column = Split(Cells(1, last_col + 2).Address, "$")(1)
re_wb.Worksheets(1).Columns(start_column & ":" & end_column).ColumnWidth = 23
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This worked well enough. If you would please add a simple example into your answer it would be worth up-voting. Link only answer don't age well due to links breaking.

Comment: Also the downside to doing this would be adding more lines to the code then needed. I think the accepted answer here is probably the best option in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the input @Mike-SMT

Answer (score 1):

Range and EntireColumn are your friends here:

```
re_wb.Worksheets(1).Range(Cells(1,last_col + 1),Cells(1,last_col + 10)).entirecolumn.ColumnWidth = 23
```

Comment: This can fail with an error 1004 if the ActiveSheet isn't `re_wb.Worksheets(1)`.  `EntireColumn` is also unnecessary.

Comment: @Comintern true but if I simple did `re_wb.Worksheets(1).Cells(1,last_col + 1)` instead it should compensate for that problem.

Comment: @Comintern true, your answer is better in that respect.

Answer (score 0):

You have a bunch of great examples here - personally I prefer to use a function that converts a number to a column letter - this way I don't have to change my syntax too much:

```
Function ColLetter(colnum As Long)

    ColLetter = Split(Cells(1, colnum).Address, "$")(1)

End Function
```

Using in your example:

```
re_wb.Worksheets(1).Columns(ColLetter(last_col + 1) & ":" & ColLetter(last_col + 2)).ColumnWidth = 23
```

Comment: There is a lot of useful examples here for sure.  I added an example to one of the answer below that is like this. It does not use a function thought. Simple in the line of code changing the column width.